# Why Flex Distribution .ipa failed to install itunes

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, itunes, ipa

I have successfully built and installed a development version of my iOS app on my iphone and ipad (from Flash builder 4.7 - flex).

I created brand new distribution certificate and provisioning profile to create a release version of the app.  I would like to test the release build before submitting it to Apple.  However whenever I try to install on my phone (already provisioned properly - works fine on dev version) I get a "Failed to Install" message.  I have tried to install the distribution and ad-hoc versions.  Neither worked.

I also have tried to load the app in Testflight but get the following error message 'Invalid Profile: does not contain provisioned devices, are you sure this is not a developer profile?'.

I don't understand how this is possible because the development versions work just fine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its an old writing, but will probably get you going http://devgirl.org/2011/06/20/flexair-for-ios-development-process-explained/
Ive managed to put my app to the appstore this way.

Comment: Yes - thanks!  I think something must be wrong with Apple Developer site the last week or so.  Thanks!